# Selector th Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how to use the Jquery selector

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

I have a table and I want to create an input within the modal, my difficulty actually is how to use the selector correctly to access the content of `<th scope="row">`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">123</th>
      <th><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal"><span class="oi" data-glyph="pencil"></span></a></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click on edit the modal opens

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Form</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

       <form method="POST" style="padding:100px">

               <div id="dvInputsUpdate"></div>



          <button name='btn-update' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `$('table.row')`

Jquery

```
    $(document).on('click', '#formModal', function() {
      var inpId = 0;
      $('#dvInputsUpdate').html('');
      $('table.row', function() {
        var chkValue = $(this).closest('th').next('td').text();
        $('#dvInputsUpdate').append($('<div class="form-group"><label >ID</label><input type="text" id="' + ("input" + inpId) + '" value="' + chkValue + '" /></div>'));

        inpId++;
      });
       return false;
    });
```

---**UPDATE**---

Thank you all so much for the answers, but you have not solved it yet. I've learned that Scope is not yet supported by html5.

I inserted a `class="update"` in th: `$('th[class="update"]')`

But this is not working yet

Comment: `$('th[scope="row"]')`.

Comment: The attribute `scope` is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Someone just downvoted all the answers. Why?

Comment: they are about as useful as the question.

Comment: I do not understand the reason for the downvotes. I'm learning from all the answers

Comment: @Gislef You can upvote.

Comment: @MrGeek Thanks, yes I did it

Comment: Thanks, anyway, even tough `scope` isn't not supported and won't do anything in HTML5, `$('th[scope="row"]')` still accesses and selects the element.

Comment: @MrGeek Your code is creating a new input but I think I'm doing something wrong in `$(this).closest('th').next('td').text();`  the input is being created without value

Answer (score 1):

`table.row` will look specifically at the `table` element and then of those elements, look for a class name of `.row`. I believe for your case, you want to look for nested `.row` classes in the `table` element so you should change it to `$('table th')`. I'm not sure what attribute `scope` is but if you want to use `.row`, you can define a `<th class="row">` instead and then use `$('table.row')`

If you really want to use the attribute `scope`, you can also specify that in jQuery by doing `${'th[scope="row"]')`

Comment: I checked again and saw he was using `scope` haha I just updated my answer xD

Comment: I assume scope is used by the framework he's using, since it's not a standard HTML tag.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, It's just not supported in HTML5. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_scope.asp

Comment: Surely `${'th[scope="row"]')` should be `$('th[scope="row"]')`

Comment: I updated my question, please see

Answer (score 0):

To access `<th scope="row">`:

```
var thScopeRow = $('th[scope="row"]');
```

Comment: I updated my question, please see

Answer (score 0):

`scope` is an attribute of `<th>`, not class, so the correct syntax would be `$('th[scope="row"]')`. In the snippet i selected this specific `th` using this method and changed the color of text just for example:

```js
$('th[scope="row"]').css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">123</th>
      <th><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal"><span class="oi" data-glyph="pencil"></span></a></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

*"I inserted a class="update" in th: $('th[class="update"]')"*
If you are using `<th class="row">123</th>` and it's only one element on the page with such class, you can get it via `$('.row')[0]`. (`[0]` is needed because `$('.row')` will find **ALL** elements on the page with such class. So think about it as an array). If you have for example 2 elements on the page with such class and want to get the second, so use `$('.row')[1]` and so on.

Comment: I updated my question, please see

Comment: @Gislef, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [the jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
Elements with attributes having a specific value can be selected via `[attributName="desiredValue"]`.

In your case: `$('th[scope="row"]')`

Comment: I updated my question, please see